# ArrayList in Session object seems to lose contents

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with retrieving and casting ArrayList from session. I get the following error:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I stored the arrayList in the session:

```
    List<UserApplication> userList = uaDAO.searchUser(eds);
    if (!userList.isEmpty()) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userList", userList);
    action_forward = EDITSUCCESS;
```

and for casting the session object to ArrayList, did the following:

```
    EditStudentForm edt = (EditStudentForm)form;
    if ((session.getAttribute("userList")) instanceof List){
    List <UserApplication> studtList = (ArrayList<UserApplication>)session.getAttribute("userList");
    }
    try {
    uaDAO.editUser(edt,studtList);
    action_forward = EDITSUCCESS;
    }
```

I'm getting the error over here in the DAO class:

```
    public void editUser(EditStudentForm edt,List studtList) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int stCode =Integer.parseInt(studtList.get(1).toString());  GETTING ERROR HERE
    if (edt.getTitle() != null && !edt.getTitle().equals(studtList.get(2).toString())) {
    sb.append("title = '").append(edt.getTitle()).append("'");
    }
    .
    .
```

Comment: Please edit your title.

Comment: Hi again,It looks like the casting is not working.Could someone pls tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
 EditStudentForm edt = (EditStudentForm)form;
    if ((session.getAttribute("userList")) instanceof List){
    List <UserApplication> studtList = (ArrayList<UserApplication>)session.getAttribute("userList");
    }
    try {
    uaDAO.editUser(edt,studtList);
    action_forward = EDITSUCCESS;
    }
```

You create a new variable 'studtList' that is never used. It's scope is only the { } pair around that one line.

There has to be another variable by that same name, studtList, in the outer scope so the 'editUser()' call can work.

*Additional Note*

As the other folks have answered, it looks like you may be doing a .get(1) and expecting the first element of the array list. Maybe. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly asking for 2nd (`studtList.get(1)`) and 3rd (`studtList.get(2)`) item in the list but never really make sure this list is big enough. Moreover your code apparently doesn't even compile:

```
if ((session.getAttribute("userList")) instanceof List){
  List <UserApplication> studtList = ///...
}
try {
  uaDAO.editUser(edt,studtList);
```

`studtList` is unaccessible in `try` block, also parenthesis in `if` statement are unmatched.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `studtList` value. 
From the error it seems your `studtList` only contain one item and you're try to get the second item with this code :

```
int stCode =Integer.parseInt(studtList.get(1).toString());
```

Change your code like this :

```
  public void editUser(EditStudentForm edt,List studtList) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(studtList.size() > 1)
        int stCode =Integer.parseInt(studtList.get(1).toString());  GETTING ERROR HERE
    if (studtList.size() > 2 && edt.getTitle() != null && !edt.getTitle().equals(studtList.get(2).toString())) {
    sb.append("title = '").append(edt.getTitle()).append("'");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `studtList` there are no two elements and size of list maybe 1 or 0 elements, you should check it before try to call `studtList.get(1)`. In `ArrayList` indexing start from 0 and if you want get first element you should call `studtList.get(0)`.